# running and testing a UVC gadget

Tags: linux, usb, xilinx, uvc

I'm trying to test a UVC I compiled for a Xilinx board. I'm following [these directions](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/e0d0e045b862da06f2a694696797b2c46ae8bc4f/Documentation/usb/gadget-testing.txt#L717). [On line 720 it says](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/e0d0e045b862da06f2a694696797b2c46ae8bc4f/Documentation/usb/gadget-testing.txt#L720) `device: run the gadget`. What is meant by **run the gadget** Is it `modprobe g_webcam`?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This kernel documentation uses the phrases "enable the gadget" and "run the gadget" interchangeably.

Note that lines 695 through 714 are describing how to enable a UVC gadget via ConfigFS. For your initial testing, using the legacy `modprobe g_webcam` will probably suffice as a less error-prone alternative.

So these three steps are distinct: enable a UVC gadget (either via `g_webcam` or `libcomposite` + the appropriate commands), enable `vivid`, and run the `uvc-gadget` userspace program.